# How to determine how much virtual memory left for my program?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I met a bad_alloc() exception. Then I attached gdb to it and called malloc_stats() :

```
Arena 0:
system bytes     =  171241472
in use bytes     =  171061480
Arena 1:
system bytes     =     335872
in use bytes     =     334296
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     = 1532186624
in use bytes     = 1532005056
max mmap regions =         44
max mmap bytes   = 1561939968
```

What does Arena 0 ,1 mean?
Does it mean I used up all my memory? Does it mean I definitely has a memory leak somwhere?
I thought every program has 4G virtual memory, the numbers listed above are no where near 4G.
Is there a way to tell how much virtual memory left?

Comment: What is your process doing that causes `bad_alloc` exception?

Comment: It is not just about how much memory is *left*. It is also about how much memory your requested in your last allocation. If you requested 4G, then of course you will run out of memory, even if "the numbers listed above are no where near 4G". In other words, you have to post more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: "I met a bad_alloc()" — that could happen if you requested e.g. `size_t(-1)` bytes, "I thought every program has 4G virtual memory" — that's not entirely true. In a usual desktop OS each 32-bit program program has at most 2 or 3 GB available, including everything — mainly heap, stack, and code areas. This amount can be further limited by the OS or by the user.

Comment: Can also happen if you have plenty of heap space, but it's fragmented. You could have 2GB of available space left, but if it's all in blocks of less than 1MB, even a 1MB request will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is partially dependent upon your operating system and hardware.  What hardware/OS are you running on?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer